# How does array_diff work?

Tags: php, performance, arrays

How does `array_diff()` work? It obviously couldn't work as follows:

```
function array_diff($arraya, $arrayb)
{
    $diffs = array();
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea)
    {
        $equaltag = 0;
        foreach ($arrayb as $valueb)     
        {
            if ($valuea == $valueb)
            {
                $equaltag =1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($equaltag == o)
        {
              $diffs[$keya]=$valuea;
        }

    }
    return $diffs;                          
}                                  //couldn't be worse than this
```

Does anyone know a better solution?

EDIT @animuson:

```
function array_diff($arraya, $arrayb)
{
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea)
    {
        if (in_array($valuea, $arrayb))
        {
            unset($arraya[$keya]);
        }
    }
    return $arraya;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

UPDATE

- [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479963/how-does-array-diff-work/6700430#6700430) for faster/better code.
- array_diff behaviour is much better in php 5.3.4, but still ~10 times slower than Leo's function.
- also it's worth noting that these functions are not strictly equivalent to `array_diff` since they don't maintain array keys, i.e. `my_array_diff(x,y) == array_values(array_diff(x,y))`.

/UPDATE

A better solution is to use [hash maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

```
function my_array_diff($a, $b) {
    $map = $out = array();
    foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
    foreach($b as $val) if(isset($map[$val])) $map[$val] = 0;
    foreach($map as $val => $ok) if($ok) $out[] = $val;
    return $out;
}

$a = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$b = array('X', 'C', 'A', 'Y');

print_r(my_array_diff($a, $b)); // B, D
```

benchmark

```
function your_array_diff($arraya, $arrayb)
{
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea)
    {
        if (in_array($valuea, $arrayb))
        {
            unset($arraya[$keya]);
        }
    }
    return $arraya;
}

$a = range(1, 10000);
$b = range(5000, 15000);

shuffle($a);
shuffle($b);

$ts = microtime(true);
my_array_diff($a, $b);
printf("ME =%.4f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);

$ts = microtime(true);
your_array_diff($a, $b);
printf("YOU=%.4f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);
```

result

```
ME =0.0137
YOU=3.6282
```

any questions? ;)

and, just for fun,

```
$ts = microtime(true);
array_diff($a, $b);
printf("PHP=%.4f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);
```

result

```
ME =0.0140
YOU=3.6706
PHP=19.5980
```

that's incredible!

Comment: OOPS!!That's really incredible!

Comment: +1. I'm surprised that this is even faster, although unlike array_diff, index association is lost: array_keys(array_diff_key(array_fill_keys($a, 1), array_fill_keys($b, 1)))

Comment: Also if $a contains duplicate values not in $b these will be lost.

Comment: PHP is much faster now
ME =0.0036
YOU=0.1217
PHP=0.0018

Comment: Same here with PHP 7.4 ME =0.0066 YOU=0.1145 PHP=0.0014

Answer (score 33):

**user187291**'s suggestion to do it in PHP via hash tables is simply great! In a rush of adrenaline taken from this phantastic idea, I even found a way to speed it up a little more (PHP 5.3.1):

```
function leo_array_diff($a, $b) {
    $map = array();
    foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
    foreach($b as $val) unset($map[$val]);
    return array_keys($map);
}
```

With the benchmark taken from user187291's posting:

```
LEO=0.0322  leo_array_diff()
ME =0.1308  my_array_diff()
YOU=4.5051  your_array_diff()
PHP=45.7114 array_diff()
```

The array_diff() performance lag is evident even at 100 entries per array.

**Note:** This solution implies that the elements in the first array are unique (or they will become unique). This is typical for a hash solution.

**Note:** The solution does not preserve indices. Assign the original index to $map and finally use array_flip() to preserve keys.

```
function array_diff_pk($a, $b) {
    $map = array_flip($a);
    foreach($b as $val) unset($map[$val]);
    return array_flip($map);
}
```

PS: I found this while looking for some array_diff() paradoxon: array_diff() took three times longer for practically the same task if used twice in the script.

Comment: Although this quite an old topic I found it only today but I couldn't reproduce what you said in order to have an associative array as output.

Comment: Added another short function `array_diff_pk` to preserve keys, also within associative arrays. Yet, I did not test the performance of `array_flip` or the overall function. Please also note, that using these replacement function will only make sense, if large arrays are handled that actually cause performance issued with the built-in (and in the meanwhile optimized) functions.

Comment: I really like your solution.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution to know how it works it to take a look at its source-code ;-)

*(Well, that's one of the powers of open source -- and if you see some possible optimization, you can submit a patch ;-) )*

For array_diff, it should be in `ext/standard` -- which means, for PHP 5.3, it should be there : [`branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/)

And, then, the [`array.c`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/array.c#3729) file looks like a plausible target ; the `php_array_diff` function, line 3381, seems to correspond to `array_diff`.

*(Good luck going through the code : it's quite long...)*

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of situations in which I think I should not have stopped using C... But, in the same have, have no regret ^^

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can speed it up a good deal more by using another array instead of unsetting. Though, this uses more memory, which might be an issue depeding on the use-case (I haven't tested actual differences in memory allocation).

```
<?php
function my_array_diff($a, $b) {
  $map = $out = array();
  foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
  foreach($b as $val) if(isset($map[$val])) $map[$val] = 0;
  foreach($map as $val => $ok) if($ok) $out[] = $val;
  return $out;
}
function leo_array_diff($a, $b) {
  $map = $out = array();
  foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
  foreach($b as $val) unset($map[$val]);
  return array_keys($map);
}
function flip_array_diff_key($b, $a) {
  $at = array_flip($a);
  $bt = array_flip($b);
  $d = array_diff_key($bt, $at);
  return array_keys($d);
}
function flip_isset_diff($b, $a) {
  $at = array_flip($a);
  $d = array();
  foreach ($b as $i)
    if (!isset($at[$i]))
      $d[] = $i;
  return $d;
}
function large_array_diff($b, $a) {
  $at = array();
  foreach ($a as $i)
    $at[$i] = 1;
  $d = array();
  foreach ($b as $i)
    if (!isset($at[$i]))
      $d[] = $i;
  return $d;
}

$functions = array("flip_array_diff_key", "flip_isset_diff", "large_array_diff", "leo_array_diff", "my_array_diff", "array_diff");
#$functions = array_reverse($functions);
$l = range(1, 1000000);
$l2 = range(1, 1000000, 2);

foreach ($functions as $function) {
  $ts = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $f = $function($l, $l2);
  }
  $te = microtime(true);
  $timing[$function] = $te - $ts;
}
asort($timing);
print_r($timing);
```

My timings are (PHP 5.3.27-1~dotdeb.0):

```
[flip_isset_diff] => 3.7415699958801
[flip_array_diff_key] => 4.2989008426666
[large_array_diff] => 4.7882599830627
[flip_flip_isset_diff] => 5.0816700458527
[leo_array_diff] => 11.086831092834
[my_array_diff] => 14.563184976578
[array_diff] => 99.379411935806
```

The three new functions were found at http://shiplu.mokadd.im/topics/performance-optimization/

Comment: I just tried these vs the built-in version with ~200k rows of real data, and the built-in was so much faster (a few seconds) that these versions didn't even finish before I got bored and cancelled the process. (~5 min?)

Answer (score 1):

As this has been brought up (see @BurninLeo's answer), what about something like this?

```
function binary_array_diff($a, $b) {
    $result = $a;
    asort($a);
    asort($b);
    list($bKey, $bVal) = each($b);
    foreach ( $a as $aKey => $aVal ) {
        while ( $aVal > $bVal ) {
            list($bKey, $bVal) = each($b);
        }
        if ( $aVal === $bVal ) {
            unset($result[$aKey]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

After performing some tests, results seem to be acceptable:

```
$a = range(1, 10000);
$b = range(5000, 15000);

shuffle($a);
shuffle($b);

$ts = microtime(true);
for ( $n = 0; $n < 10; ++$n ) {
    array_diff($a, $b);
}
printf("PHP    => %.4f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);

$ts = microtime(true);
for ( $n = 0; $n < 10; ++$n ) {
    binary_array_diff($a, $b);
}
printf("binary => %.4f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);

$binaryResult = binary_array_diff($a, $b);
$phpResult    = array_diff($a, $b);
if ( $binaryResult == $phpResult && array_keys($binaryResult) == array_keys($phpResult) ) {
    echo "returned arrays are the same\n";
}
```

Output:

```
PHP    => 1.3018
binary => 1.3601
returned arrays are the same
```

Of course, PHP code cannot perform as good as C code, therefore there's no wonder that PHP code is a bit slower.

Answer (score -2):

From PHP: "Returns an array containing all the entries from array1  that are not present in any of the other arrays."

So, you just check *array1* against all *arrayN* and any values in *array1* that don't appear in any of those arrays will be returned in a new array.

You don't necessarily even need to loop through all of *array1*'s values. Just for all the additional arrays, loop through their values and check if each value is `in_array($array1, $value)`.

Comment: -1 It is more complex than that. There are advanced algorithms and data structures being used. See pascal's answer.

Comment: It is still a basic idea of what is happening and *is* a better solution than what he had.