# handling large arrays with array_diff

Tags: php

I have been trying to compare two arrays. Using array_intersect presents no problems. When using array_diff and arrays with ~5,000 values, it works. When I get to ~10,000 values, the script dies when I get to array_diff. Turning on error_reporting did not produce anything.

I tried creating my own array_diff function:

```
function manual_array_diff($arraya, $arrayb) {
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea) {
        if (in_array($valuea, $arrayb)) {
            unset($arraya[$keya]);
        }
    }
    return $arraya;
}
```

source: [How does array_diff work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479963/how-does-array-diff-work)

I would expect it to be less efficient that than the official array_diff, but it can handle arrays of ~10,000. Unfortunately, both array_diffs fail when I get to ~15,000.

I tried the same code on a different machine and it runs fine, so it's not an issue with the code or PHP. There must be some limit set somewhere on that particular server. Any idea how I can get around that limit or alter it or just find out what it is?

Comment: What data did you test that with?

Comment: Probably it's because this algorithm is O(N^2).

Comment: Are you running this in a browser or a command line?

Comment: The data is a bunch of IDs. Running it in a browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having encountered the exact same problem, I was really hoping for an answer here.

So, I had to find my own way around it and came up with the following ugly kludge that is working for me with arrays of around 50,000 elements. It is based on your observation that array_intersect works but array_diff doesn't.

Sooner or later this will also overflow the resource limitations, in which case it will be necessary to chunk the arrays and deal with smaller bits. We will cross that bridge when we come to it.

```
function new_array_diff($arraya, $arrayb) {
    $intersection = array_intersect($arraya, $arrayb);
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea) {
        if (!isset($intersection[$keya])) {
            $diff[$keya] = $valuea;
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 60     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
memory_limit = 32M          ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
```

Could differences in these setting or alternatively in machine performance be causing the problems? Did you check your web server error logs (if you run this through one)?

Comment: It only takes a few seconds to execute, so execution time is not a problem.

Manually lowering memory_limit on one machine did kill the script. However, setting memory_limit higher on the the other machine did not solve the problem.

In case you are curious, it was initially 40M on the machine that was causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this is running in a browser. Try running the script via command line and see if the result is different.