# Is array_diff a good way to compare columns with 10 thousand entries?

Tags: php

I have two tables and I want to compare a particular column of both using `array_diff`. One column has more than 10,000 entries and other has 25 entries max. Is fetching both columns into arrays and taking array_difference is good way to compare them or will it be too slow?

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean database tables? If so, why not let the database server to the work instead of `array_diff`?

Comment: because I want to compare than put into new column of some table...

Comment: You could still do that with a [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Comment: read comment to next answer. hope you will get my point.

Comment: In that case, why don't you: 1. `SELECT` all the non-matching rows from your database, 2. Display them to the user using PHP and show a form for them to select the ones they want to `INSERT`, and 3. `INSERT` the new rows. There's not need for `array_diff()`.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes: what u wanna say.. But can u help me with a piece of code to select non matching row without using array difference. I mean query to select different entries.

Comment: Without knowing the name of your tables, it's difficult. But you'd want something like this: `SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`field1` = `table1`.`field1` WHERE `table2`.`id` IS NULL`. This would return all rows from `table1` that don't have a matching `table2` row.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 tables, then I assume that those tables are from a DB. You would better write a SQL query to do that join/difference and let just the DB handle this

Comment: I want PHP to do that. I am creating a list that takes two tables compare the column and than ask user if put particular record in Db or not.... and can't be possible with DB.. As approval and all require PHP to implement

Comment: You could get straight from the DB only the records that are different - this way you don't have to get tens of thousands of records to the application level

Comment: Actually I have song main table and new album table.. Now I wish to approve album table list either to put into song mail table or not. for that fetching both columns in array and than asking moderater to approve. Please tell me if any other solution using Db query. Give me that query.

Comment: give us the structure of your tables and tell us based on which columns do you want the intersection

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985799/handling-large-arrays-with-array-diff/3362441#3362441) solves your problem,

> Having encountered the exact same
>   problem, I was really hoping for an
>   answer here.
>
> So, I had to find my own way around it
>   and came up with the following ugly
>   kludge that is working for me with
>   arrays of around 50,000 elements. It
>   is based on your observation that
>   array_intersect works but array_diff
>   doesn't.
>
> Sooner or later this will also
>   overflow the resource limitations, in
>   which case it will be necessary to
>   chunk the arrays and deal with smaller
>   bits. We will cross that bridge when
>   we come to it.

Code :

```
 function new_array_diff( $arraya, $arrayb )   
     { 
     $intersection = array_intersect( $arraya, $arrayb ); 
     foreach( $arraya as $keya => $valuea )
         {
            if ( !isset($intersection[$keya]) )
              {
               $diff[$keya] = $valuea;
               }
           } 
      return $diff;    
    }
```

Comment: I hope array_intersact may not slow down the process.. for 50k entries